# How to set Dart to stable channel with Flutter on beta channel (to avoid null safety opt in)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, intellij-idea

I need to have **Flutter** set to the **Beta** channel (Flutter 1.25.0-8.3.pre at the time of writing) but not to "opt in" into the null safety feature, which is why I'm manually setting the **Dart** version to the **Stable** channel.

As I'm using **Intellij IDE**, I've tried defining the Dart SDK path in `Settings` but once I change that to the path of a stable version (which I seperately setup in standalone location) flutter run no longer works through the IDE. Just running `flutter run` in a terminal works.

Just to shed more light on the matter. It seems that once I change `Dart SDK path` in settings the `Flutter SDK path` is being unset and vice versa.

*side note: I need flutter beta because of its support for web*

Answer (score 2):

switch to beta channel

```
flutter channel beta
```

update to latest version

```
flutter upgrade
```

dart-sdk comes with flutter, location is:

```
flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk
```

set this for dart-sdk path in intellij-idea

then in pubspec.yaml you can define the dart version you want for current project

i am using this version for non-null safety projects:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.9.0 <3.0.0"
```

this version for null safety projects:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0-29.10.beta <3.0.0'
```

note: i am on dev 1.26, my newest project is running null safety feature but older projects are on non null safety because they are already in production and i dont want to migrate them. Everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about Flutter channels in [Official Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading).