# How to fix this Flutter create test error

Tags: flutter

[image: Flutter error]

Could anyone help me how to fix this flutter error I couldn't identify what its problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65831599/how-to-set-dart-to-stable-channel-with-flutter-on-beta-channel-to-avoid-null-sa

Comment: This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370294/git-could-not-resolve-host-github-com-error-while-cloning-remote-repository-in

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)